# Adding folders to every subfolder, when white spaces exist

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I have a main folder, with a lot of subfolders inside e.g

```
C:\Main Folder\Bob James
C:\Main Folder\John Smith
```

And for each of these folders I want to add the folder Family Members

I tried using

```
FOR /d %A IN ("C:\Main Folder\*") DO mkdir %A\"Family Members"
```

which didn't work, not did

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\"Main Folder"\*) DO mkdir %A\"Family Members"
```

but when I did

```
FOR /d %A IN (C:\Test\*) DO mkdir %A\"Family Members"
```

it works, are there anyways to make these work with the white spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You were so close, just move the quote a bit :-)

```
FOR /d %A IN ("C:\Main Folder\*") DO mkdir "%A\Family Members"
```

The `%A` must be quoted because it contains a space. When your loop executes `mkdir %A\"Family Members"`, and %A contains `C:\Main Folder\Bob James`, then the command becomes `mkdir C:\Main Folder\Bob James\"Family Members"`. This attempts to create 3 folders, because the leading bit is not quoted:

```
C:\Main
Folder\Bob
James\"Family Members"
```